# Wordpress find and replace image URLs not working

Tags: wordpress, url, replace, find, migrate

I have migrated a wordpress site from a subdomain on my host, to my client's domain on their host. Only the image URL's were still linking to my subdomain. I used a find and replace plugin as well as going straight through phpmyadmin to modify the database with a find and replace command as well. I believe I was successful in changing the URLs, but apparently they are wrong, as there is an extra folder in the URLs. Now when I try to correct this, find and replace does not detect the (incorrect) URL I am trying to replace with the correct one. I have tried many variations of the URLs, from the entire thing to just parts. Any thoughts?

Trying to replace:

http://www.themaggiedress.com/public_html/themaggiedress/wp-content/uploads/

with:

http://www.themaggiedress.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/

in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your permalinks?

Also make sure your 'WordPress Address (URL)' and 'Site Address (URL)' are correct in general settings? (It should not reflect the Sub Domain)

You can also manually look for the images in your Wordpress directory and make sure the links are right when investigating them in the browsers console.